# Are presta valve cores universal?

Tags: valves, presta, sealant

Is a Stan's presta valve necessarily compatible with presta valve cores from other manufacturers? Or do they all have different threads?

Comment: Can confirm compatibility with qtubes valve cores and stans tubeless presta valve.

Answer (score 10):

I always save the core out of blown tubes and have never had them not compatible.   At the bike store you just see one jar.  Might someone come out with non-standard - it could happen.

Comment: cheers. It won't be too expensive to replace the ones I keep snapping when pumping then :/

Comment: How are you pumping?  I have never snapped one.

Comment: It never happened to me until I bought this rubbish giant floor pump. It's probably that

Comment: I've snapped a few in the past. I found it helps to not unscrew the valvle completely when inflating. Usually better to just give it a couple turns to the point where when depressed the air escapes.  If air can get out, air can get in, and usually unscrewing it more gives the screw a higher probability of bent and breaking off.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the same as my experience. I mostly swap the cores and have never had an incompatibility issue

Comment: I went through a few of pumps before I bought a nice one.  I think an expensive pump is more economical.

Comment: The ones which are not compatible are generally the presta valve'd tubes without replaceable cores.

Comment: @Batman The question is threads on a core.   Establishes replaceable core for me.

Comment: He's got a point, trying to screw a valve core onto a non-replaceable valve is a real nightmare ;)

Comment: @NeMo Are you not even sure if you have a removable core?

Comment: Um, yes frisbee, yes I am sure. Just a silly joke on my part, never mind :)